# Laravel prioritize or operator in relation query (hasMany). How to add parenthesis?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

The events method in my model returns all related events from the database. The code below is working fine, the only problem is dat it don't prioritze the or. (See `orWhereHas`)

```
public function events()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Event::class)
        ->orWhereHas('organisations', function(Builder $query){
            $query->where('organisation_id', $this->id);
        });
}
```

When I extend the query somewhere else in the code, it goes wrong:

```
$model->events()->whereNull('some_field')
```

Because it should prioritize the OR operator. But I don't know how to do that in this case because I am imitating the query from a model relation.

So the question is: how to add parenthesis in the query to prioritize the or operator?

Comment: What is the error? I think what you are trying to do does not make sense. You are getting all events, related to the parent model, but then you are also saying where the relationship `organisations` has `organisation_id = $this->id`. That makes no sense because what will you get back? Events where the parent model is present in `organisations`? I think you are mixing up something, not sure what as I do not know your schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move the logic outside the relationship method and use a `where`/`orWhere` Closure.

```php
public function events()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Event::class)
}
```

```php
$model->events()
    ->where(function ($sub) {
        $sub->orWhereHas('organisations', function(Builder $query){
                $query->where('organisation_id', $this->id);
            })
            ->orWhereNull('some_field');
    })
```